# How to change C++ include guards in CLion?

Tags: c++, clion, include-guards

When CLion creates a header file it adds include guard strings like this:

```
#ifndef PROJECTNAME_FILENAME_H
#define PROJECTNAME_FILENAME_H

/* ... code ... */

#endif //PROJECTNAME_FILENAME_H
```

But I want just `FILENAME_H` without the `PROJECTNAME_` prefix. How to change it in CLion settings?

Comment: You should avoid using only `FILENAME_H`, it is not that rare to have multiple files with the same name in a project.

Comment: This wouldn't help in this case since the other header (with the same filename) would also use the include guards PROJECTNAME_FILENAME_H

Comment: One alternative would be to use `#pragma once` instead of the `#ifndef` include guards. The template used for header file creation can be changed under `Settings->Editor->File and Code Templates`.

Comment: Some sources say that with `#define` compilation is faster. And `#pragma once` is not a part of pre-C++11 versions of standard.
I don't believe `${PROJECT}_${FILE}_H` is hardcoded in CLion.

Comment: @Kroll, what sources say that?

Comment: @TamásSzelei: I remember GCC themselves saying something related (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Once-Only-Headers.html): _"CPP optimizes even further. It remembers when a header file has a wrapper ‘#ifndef’. If a subsequent ‘#include’ specifies that header, and the macro in the ‘#ifndef’ is still defined, it does not bother to rescan the file at all."_

Comment: The pattern - once I "discovered" it some 15 or so years ago - I use is `<FILENAME>_<EXT>_INCLUDED_<YYYYMMDD>`. When I happen to write `2d/Vector.hh` and `3d/Vector.hh` on the same day, I spontaneously add something additional, like wall time (`VECTOR_HH_INCLUDED_20181003_1953`) or folder (`MATH_2D_VECTOR_HH_INCLUDED_20181003`). Of course it's still not perfect (some library may also come with `VECTOR_HH_INCLUDED_20181003`), but in reality, the vector-example is the only incident that happened to me. The `INCLUDED` part is just for aesthetics.

Answer (score 9):

Bit late to this question, but I've got a slightly more involved solution that'll handle this without the need for manual post-processing regardless of file extension:

1. Head into your **File and Code Templates** - The other answers already detail how to do this.
2. In the **File and Code Templates** settings page, change to the **Includes** tab.
3. Click the `+` to create a new Include template. **Name** it something like `IncludeGuard` and set the **Extension** to `h`.
4. Input the following for the contents. **Make sure you don't include any blank lines before or after.**

```
#macro( includeGuard $filename $ext )
#set( $ucfull = ${filename.toUpperCase().replace('-', '_')} )
#set( $extidx = ${ucfull.lastIndexOf(".")} )
#set( $extstart = $extidx + 1 )
#if( $extidx > -1 )
#set( $ucname = ${ucfull.substring(0,$extidx)} )
#set( $ucext = ${ucfull.substring($extstart)} )
#else
#set( $ucname = $!{ucfull} )
#set( $ucext = ${ext.toUpperCase()} )
#end
${ucname}_${ucext}##
#end##
```

5. Change back to the **Files** tab, and find the `C Header File` or `C++ Class Header` file depending on which language you're looking to update.
6. Change the contents of this file template to:

```
#parse("IncludeGuard.h")##
#set( $blank = "" )
#[[#ifndef]]# #includeGuard(${NAME} "h")${blank}
#[[#define]]# #includeGuard(${NAME} "h")${blank}

// ...

#[[#endif]]# // #includeGuard(${NAME} "h")
```

---

If everything works as intended, attempting to create a **C Header File** using the name `test-include-guard` or `test-include-guard.h` should both result in the following:

```c
#ifndef TEST_INCLUDE_GUARD_H
#define TEST_INCLUDE_GUARD_H

// ...

#endif /* TEST_INCLUDE_GUARD_H */
```

---

Few notes:

- If you need to change the file extension, change the `includeGuard(${NAME} "h")` parts to use whatever extension you want for the second parameter. The template will attempt to parse the file extension from `${NAME}`, but `${NAME}` only contains the file extension if you explicitly enter it into the new filename dialog.
- The current state of whitespace handling in the Velocity templates used by CLion is a shit show, so you'll need to work around this as I did if you decide to further customize the templates. General guidelines:

  - If you're experiencing undesired linebreaks, you'll want to try adding a terminating line comment `##` to the ends of lines before it.
  - If you find yourself in the oppostie scenario, (missing an expected linebreak) you can work around this with the `#set( $blank = "" )` strategy I utilized above.
- Most of the IntelliJ-based IDEs seem to cache the compilation of **Include** templates the first time they get passed into `#parse()`. If you make changes to an Include template after this point, you'll usually need to use the **File** > **Invalidate Caches/Restart** menu command before the changes propagate.

Answer (score 8):

1. Settings->Editor->File and Code Templates->Files
2. change `${INCLUDE_GUARD}` into `_${NAME}_H_`

For example, if your file name is: `clion.h`, then `_${NAME}_H_` is rendered as `_clion_H_`, because `${NAME}` is rendered as the filename (without extension).

Answer (score 1):

**File | Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates** for Windows and Linux

**CLion | Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates** for OS X

```
#[[#ifndef]]# BASE_${HEADER_FILENAME}
#[[#define]]# BASE_${HEADER_FILENAME}


#[[#endif]]# //BASE_${HEADER_FILENAME}
```

>

```
#ifndef BASE_test_h
#define BASE_test_h

#endif //BASE_test_h
```

select **BASE_test_h**  and press **CTRL + SHIFT + U** to upper case

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest [doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/header-guards.html#) (2019.3, but it may work in earlier versions, too) you can navigate to the *Naming Convention* tab under **Settings / Preferences | Editor | Code Style | C/C++**.

There you'll find a field that allows you to easily change the header guard pattern. No need to add custom templates anymore.

[image]